# What is this expansion called? $x= \sum \frac{a_n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

What is this expansion called? For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x$ may be uniquely written as
$$
x= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}
$$
where $a_0 = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $a_n \leq n$, $a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) calls it the factorial number system. I have also seen it referred at as the Cantor factorial notation or expansion.